# Error : Struct not defined correctly

Tags: c, struct, c-preprocessor, gpio

I am doing some GPIO with a beaglebone and currently have this in my code:

```
#include <linux/gpio.h>         //for GPIO

char label[] = "sys/kernel/debug/gpio";

struct gpio xx[] = {
    { gpio1, GPIOF_DIR_OUT|GPIOF_INIT_LOW, label },
    { gpio2, GPIOF_DIR_OUT|GPIOF_INIT_LOW, label },
    { gpio3, GPIOF_DIR_OUT|GPIOF_INIT_LOW, label },
    { gpio4, GPIOF_DIR_OUT|GPIOF_INIT_LOW, label },
    { gpio5, GPIOF_DIR_OUT|GPIOF_INIT_LOW, label },
    { gpio6, GPIOF_DIR_OUT|GPIOF_INIT_LOW, label },
    { gpio7, GPIOF_DIR_OUT|GPIOF_INIT_LOW, label },
    { gpio8, GPIOF_DIR_OUT|GPIOF_INIT_LOW, label },
    { gpio9, GPIOF_DIR_OUT|GPIOF_INIT_LOW, label },
    { gpio10, GPIOF_DIR_OUT|GPIOF_INIT_HIGH, label },
    };
```

where gpio#, are all defined as integers.  GPIOF_DIR_OUT and GPIOF_DIR_LOW are functions within "linux/gpio.h".

The structure is not declared inside a function.  I believe this is my problem but I am unsure how it is declared wrong.  I have seen other threads for this, but nothing really helped with my problem.  I think the problem is the fact I'm calling a function from within my struct.  If someone could verify, or help me fix this that would be great.

Comment: your code does not call any functions, try using `GPIOF_DIR_OUT()`.

Comment: What is the definition for **struct gpio** ? Also I assume gpio1~10 and label are all macros or enums. They cannot be variables.

Answer (score 1):

If `gpio1` through `gpio10` are integers, as you say, then what you have declared here is, as the compiler says, invalid.  Global variable initializers in C have to be *constant expressions*, which means no variables allowed!

Answer (score 1):

> [...] where gpio#, are all defined as integers [...]

I assumed that you probably mean something like:

```
const int gpio1 = 42;
const int gpio2 = 84;
const int gpio3 = 43;
// etc.
```

However, since `xx` is initialized in the global scope, it is allocated and initialized at compile-time. However, based on my assumption, `gpio1` and friends are allocated and initialized at run-time, so obviously the compiler tells you that it can't initialize `xx`.

You will need to use a constant expression (or a macro that will expand into a literal constant) for this to work. Per example, you'd do:

```
enum {
    gpio1 = 42, 
    gpio2 = 84, 
    gpio3 = 43, 
    // etc.
};
```

...or:

```
#define gpio1 42
#define gpio2 84
#define gpio3 43
// etc.
```

And before you ask, `label` decays into a pointer to a string literal in this context. That makes it a constant expression, so this one is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The GPIOF_DIR_OUT, GPIOF_INIT_LOW, GPIOF_INIT_HIGH are macros, not functions. So this is not the reason.

I think this issue maybe related to the gpio1~gpio10 definitions, are these things are variables or macros?

Answer (score 0):

Make `gpio1` etc `const` values and it will compile, for example:

```
const unsigned gpio1 = 1;
```

Comment: A variable that is defined as `const` is not considered a constant expression in C, so no, this won't work.

Comment: Hmmm, I compiled it before posting and it worked.  Looking more closely, `clang` accepts it but `gcc` doesn't; both with -std=c99

Comment: See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53091#c3. Note that the above would be allowed in C++ though.